# PostgreSQL Password Authentication Error...but cannot find account

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, authentication

I'm getting the following error within the PostgreSQL log file. When an external service is calling the DB for map routing, the following error appears. However, within “Login/Group Roles”, the user doesn't exist.

I've also checked `pg_hba.conf` and the User stated there is `Administrator`.

Where is this account being referenced? I'm struggling to get any additional logging in order to tell me.

Help would be appreciated :)

```
2019-11-29 11:14:32 GMT FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Admin"
2019-11-29 11:14:32 GMT DETAIL:  Role "Admin" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 88: "host   all all samenet md5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a user that exists for the login.
Like the error message says, there is no user `Admin`.